# Passing array from another method as parameter

Tags: java, file-io, spell-checking

I'm trying to read a text file, then compare the words to a dictionary text file, and print out any words that aren't found in the `dictionary.txt` file. My problem is that I can't figure out how to pass the dictionary array from the `dictionaryRead()` method to the `binarySearch()` method as a parameter.

```
    public class spellChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        spellChecker spellcheck = new spellChecker();
        spellcheck.textFileRead(spellcheck.dictionaryRead());
    }

    private String[] dictionaryArray; 
    public String[] dictionaryRead() throws Exception
    {
        // Find and read the file into array
        String token = "";

        // Use scanner for input file
        Scanner dictionaryScan = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*"); 

        List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Check for next line in text file
        while (dictionaryScan.hasNext()) 
        {
          token = dictionaryScan.next();
          dictionary.add(token);
        }
        dictionaryScan.close();

        dictionaryArray = dictionary.toArray(new String[0]);

        return dictionaryArray;
    }

    public void textFileRead(String [] dictionaryArray) throws Exception
    {
        //Get input file path from user
        System.out.println("Please enter a file path: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputFile = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();

        // Find and read the file
        String word = "";
        // Use scanner for input file
        Scanner inputFileScan = new Scanner(new File(inputFile + ".txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");

        //Check for next line in text file
        while (inputFileScan.hasNext()) 
        {
          word = inputFileScan.nextLine();
          binarySearch(word);
        }

        inputFileScan.close();
    }

    public void binarySearch(String word)
    {
        int first = 0;
        int last  = dictionaryArray.length;

        while (first < last) {
          int mid = first + ((last - first) / 2);
          if (word.compareTo(dictionaryArray[mid]) < 0) {
              last = mid;
          } else if (word.compareTo(dictionaryArray[mid]) > 0) {
              first = mid + 1;
          } else {
              if(word != dictionaryArray[mid]){
                System.out.println(word);
              }
          }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to call `binarySearch()` from `dictionaryRead()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches to doing that, since you are creating an instance of your class, you could make `dictionaryArray` a field in your class:

```
private String[] dictionaryArray; 

public void dictionaryRead() throws FileNotFoundException {
    ...
    // Note how String[] is removed on the line below:
    dictionaryArray = dictionary.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Now `dictionaryArray` is visible to all instance methods of your class, so you can simply reference it by name in the `binarySearch` method:

```
public void binarySearch(String word) {
    // Use dictionaryArray instead of arr
    ...
}
```

Comment: This helped out! I still have a problem with it not printing any words that don't match dictionary.txt. I believe it's a problem with my logic in the `binarySearch()` method. I've updated my code above to show what I'm currently working with.

Comment: @Rainwater You may want to separate out the binary search issue into a separate question, and explain what's going on (i.e. words that do not match dictionary.txt do not get printed).

Answer (score 1):

slightly change your structure as

```
public class spellChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        spellChecker spellcheck = new spellChecker();

        spellcheck.textFileRead(spellcheck.dictionaryRead());
    }

    public String [] dictionaryRead() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // Find and read the file into array
        String token = "";

        // Use scanner for input file
        Scanner dictionaryScan = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");

        List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Check for next line in text file
        while (dictionaryScan.hasNext()) 
        {
          token = dictionaryScan.next();
          dictionary.add(token);
        }
        dictionaryScan.close();

        String[] dictionaryArray = dictionary.toArray(new String[0]);

        return dictionaryArray;
    }

    public void textFileRead(String [] dictionaryArray) throws IOException
    {
        //Get input file path from user
        System.out.println("Please enter a file path: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputFile = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();

        // Find and read the file
        String word = "";
        // Use scanner for input file
        Scanner inputFileScan = new Scanner(new File(inputFile + ".txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");

        //Check for next line in text file
        while (inputFileScan.hasNext()) 
        {
          word = inputFileScan.next();
          binarySearch(dictionaryArray[], word);
        }

        inputFileScan.close();
    }

    public void binarySearch(String[] arr, String word)
    {
        int first = 0;
        int last  = arr.length;

        while (first < last) {
          int mid = first + ((last - first) / 2);
          if (word.compareTo(arr[mid]) < 0) {
              last = mid;
          } else if (word.compareTo(arr[mid]) > 0) {
              first = mid + 1;
          } else {
              if(word != arr[mid]){
                System.out.println(arr[mid]);
              }
          }
        }  
    }
}
```